# Keycloak -> How to fetch permissions attached to a single role or group

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

Scenerio :
Use Groups for multi tenancy (One user working for different organizations) -

1. Create one group for each org like **group_org1, group_org2** etc.
2. Provide permissions to above groups using group policy (using confidential client authorization tab). **Ex :- group_org1 has permission on resource1 and group_org2 has permission on resource2.**
3. Assign above groups to a user , **hence user will have 2 groups and, permission on resource1 & resource1**.
4. Now groups fetched for this user will be used as organizations in application.
5. **When selected org1 then application will work according to the permissions attached to group org1 i.e. permission only on resource1**.

Question :
As of now if I try to fetch authorization permissions for a user then keycloak will give me combined permissions attached to both the groups i.e. on resource1 and resource2 . **I need to fetch permissions attached to single group using keycloak rest-api.** (after fetching this specific permissions I can authorize user in the application for given resource)

Hope I made my question a bit clear.

Comment: Anyone knows solution to this?